# Bucle con temporizador y condiciones (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Acabo de empezar en el mundo de Javascript y me surgen dudas...

Tengo la siguiente función, quiero que se repita mientras el valor aleatorio sea 204. Cuando el código sea 200 debe parar, si es 500 notificar error y parar también. La petición se repetirá cada segundo (de ahí el uso de setInterval aunque no sé si los estoy haciendo correctamente)

Además quiero que se intente X veces y también pare... No sé cómo implementarlo, podía ser con un contador?

```js
var myArray = [200, 500, 404, 204];
var encontrado = false;
var cont = 0;

var repeticion = setInterval(function aleatorio() {

  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];


  if (rand == 200) {
    console.log("HTTP 200! Encontrado!");
    encontrado = true;

  } else if (rand == 500) {
    console.log("HTTP 500! Error interno del servidor");
    encontrado = true;

  } else if (rand == 204) {
    console.log("HTTP 204!");

  } else if (rand == 404) {
    console.log("HTTP 404!");
  }

  cont++;

  if (encontrado === true) {
    stopFunction();
  }

}, 1000);

function stopFunction() {
  clearInterval(repeticion);
}
```

Es una pequeña simulación, ya que esto después funcionará con respuestas reales de un servidor y con otra función.

Intenté hacer todo esto con un do-while, pero lógicamente el tema del temporizador no era compatible. Si alguien sabe cómo también sirve como solución alternativa.

¿Cómo puedo optimizar mi código y corregir lo que falta? Gracias

Comment: Podrias explicar que contiene `myArray`?

Comment: Ya vi que te diste cuenta, se me olvidó anotar esa parte, pero efectivamente es así: var myArray = [200, 500, 404, 204];

Comment: Perfecto, he agregado el ejemplo segun lo que comentas, espero te sirva

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Codigo

```js
/* Arreglo de errores */
var arreglo = [
  200, 204, 500, 404
];

/* Limite de repeticiones */
var limite = 10;

/* Contador de repeticiones */
var contador = 0;

/* Bandera */
var encontrado = false;

/* Interval */
var intervalo = setInterval(function() {

  var resultado = arreglo[Math.floor(Math.random() * arreglo.length)];

  if (resultado == 200) {
    console.log("HTTP 200! Encontrado!");
    encontrado = true;

  } else if (resultado == 500) {
    console.log("HTTP 500! Error interno del servidor");
    encontrado = true;

  } else if (resultado == 204) {
    console.log("HTTP 204!");

  } else if (resultado == 404) {
    console.log("HTTP 404!");
  }

  if (encontrado === true && contador >= limite) {
    stopFunction();
  }

  contador++;

}, 1000);

function stopFunction() {
  clearInterval(intervalo);
}
```

---

### Explicacion

Basado en lo que expones en tu pregunta, para poder realizar un numero determinado de repeticiones y que no se cierre, podrias tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

#### Primero

Hemos declarado unas variables que estaran fuera de la funcion del intervalo:

```
/* Arreglo de errores */
var arreglo = [
  200, 204, 500, 404
];

/* Limite de repeticiones */
var limite = 10;

/* Contador de repeticiones */
var contador = 0;

/* Bandera */
var encontrado = false;
```

En este caso cambiando el valor de la variable `limite`, el codigo se va a ejecutar solo esa cantidad de veces, para el ejemplo dejamos 10.

La variable `contador` sirve para contar las repeticiones y esta sera comparada con `limite` en cada ejecucion.

La variable `bandera` evaluara si se encontro o no el valor deseado.

#### Segundo

Al final de la funcion, ejecutamos esta sentencia:

```
  if (encontrado === true && contador >= limite) {
    stopFunction();
  }
```

Lo que indicamos al programa en este caso es algo como:

> Si encuentra algun valor y **si** se llego al limite, detengamos este programa.

Asi el cuerpo de la funcion se ejecutara multiples veces, sin necesidad de ejecutar multiples veces la misma funcion.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias por tu solución!

Answer (score 2):

Cuando he tenido que usar setInterval lo utilizo de la siguiente manera:

```
var refreshInterval =  window.setInterval(function(){
   //Aquí puedes poner el Math.random()
/* lo que quieras que se ejecute */ verifyCode();  }, 
  /* El intervalo de tiempo */  1000);
```

Ahora supongamos que creamos un método que se ejecuta cada segundo (1000) llamado verifyCode() y debe recibir el código que en este caso generas con un Math.random():

```
function verifyCode(rand){
   if (rand == 200) {
            console.log("HTTP 200! Encontrado!");
            encontrado = true;

   } else if (rand == 500) {
            console.log("HTTP 500! Error interno del servidor");
            encontrado = true;

   } else if (rand == 204) {
            console.log("HTTP 204!");

   } else if (rand == 404) {
            console.log("HTTP 404!");
   }

   if (encontrado === true) {
            clearInterval(refreshInterval);
  }
 }
```

Traté de no cambiar mucho la lógica interna, ya es dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, el clearInterval() lo encontré en [Stop setInterval call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)